# Command sequence in 1 block in elisp

Tags: elisp, emacs24

How can i run multiple commands one after another in a single block in elisp.
something like this but not precisely,

```
((message "first message")
  (message "second message"))
```

Output must be,

```
first message
second message
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(progn BODY...)` will evaluate BODY forms sequentially and return value of last one. (from emacs help)

```
(progn
 (message "first message")
 (message "second message"))
```